# Add xml element with attirbute in between existing attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to add an xml element and attribute between an existing one.
I have xml template that looks lik e this:

```
<INPUT>
 <LOGIN user="cat" password="meow" />
     <REC>

    </REC>
  </INPUT>
```

I'm looking to add an element and atribute between `<REC></REC>`
treid formattging soemthing like this but it sticks it after LOGIN not REC

```
                 IEnumerable<XElement> list = doc.Element("INPUT").Elements("LOGIN");
             var addElement = new XElement("an", new XAttribute("id", i));
             list.Last().AddAfterSelf(addElement);
```

Comment: "attribute" has a very specific meaning in SGML, and according to that meaning, `REC` is not an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add it as a *child* of `REC`. That's easy:

```
// If there are multiple `REC` elements, you'll need to work out which one you want
var recElement = doc.Descendants("REC").First();
recElement.Add(new XElement("an", new XAttribute("id", i)));
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works great. Do you have any good references that explains xml like root element, attribute, and child?

Comment: @ERead: In terms of LINQ to XML, or in general?